# C# Memory Stream/OpenXML sometimes adds extra characters to file name

Tags: c#, openxml, filepath, memorystream

I export an Excel file using OpenXML and MemoryStream and it sometimes adds extra characters to the file path. It doesn't happen every time. When I first load it up for the day it seems to work just fine, but after running it a bunch it starts to add extra characters. I assume there's a memory leak or buffer problem, but I don't know enough about it to fix it.

My code is:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{                
     report.CreatePackage(stream);

     System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
     System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
     System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Report_" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".xlsx");
     stream.Position = 0;
     stream.CopyTo(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
     System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
     System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
     System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
 }
```

It will look something like this in the filepath: Report_09_14_2016CAOFMLJL.xlsx instead of just the report and date.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware, that `Response.Clear()` doesn't clear the headers? Putting it the other way around: does calling `Response.ClearHeaders()` at an appropriate place change anything towards a happy end?

Comment: It appears that on the first time running it, it still adds the extra characters, but every subsequent time after that works. I'm not sure if that's the headers or why it doesn't work on the first time.

Comment: The code doesn't match the string. You are adding `".xlsx"`, but there is `".XLSX"` extension in the result (and this difference probably explains why `"CAOFMLJL.XLSX"` is added).

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. Got shift happy. It's edited to reflect actual file name.

Comment: On my machine  DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() prints 14/09/2016, I'm guessing it has to do with system settings. Maybe try this instead DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy"). Slashes are not valid in file names on Windows.

Comment: As an aside, you ought to enclose the filename in quotes and you have the wrong MIME type; the one you are using is correct for xls, but for xlsx you should use `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`.

Comment: Ah did not know that. Thanks petelids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my machine DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() prints 14/09/2016, I'm guessing it has to do with system settings. Maybe try this instead (or any other formay you require):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy")
```

Slashes are not valid in file names on Windows.

Comment: I think this is the case. I've tested it a few dozen times and haven't had the extra characters added. However, it seemed to only add it sometimes so I'll do some more testing and will mark this as the answer later if it doesn't come back.